# How to generate apidoc automatically for existing sails js project?

Tags: sails.js

I am working on sails js project. How can i generate api documentation automatically for all the existing apis (With its JSON request and response)?

Comment: Hey, I want to thank you for this question! Really nice answers bellow...

Answer (score 4):

I'm using APIdoc for all my Sails projects. This is the way I do it:

First install apidoc and rimraf as development deps:

```
npm install apidoc rimraf --save-dev
```

Then edit your package json and add script to create apidoc:

```
...package.json file
"scripts": {
    "docs": "rimraf public/docs && apidoc -i config/ -o public/docs",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
... rest of package.json file
```

Of course, public/docs can be any folder you wish to put docs in... I'm using public/docs

Next, just add apidoc specific comments inside your config/routes.js or if you wish to write comments inside controllers, change upper script to run -i /api/controllers instead of -i /config

One bonus trick that I use is serving docs directly with sails so its available on localhost:1337/docs by editing .sailsrc file and adding this:

```
{
  "generators": {
    "modules": {}
  },
  "hooks": {
  },
  "paths": {
    "public": "public" //name of the folder where all my public assets are (including docs)
  }
}
```

Whenever you want fresh copy of docs, just run:

```
npm run docs
```

You could also automatize this by adding docs generation inside start script inside package.json or even inside config/bootstrap.js. But I found it much better by manually calling docs when I need it. It speeds up lift process.

EDIT: forgot to mention that you can pass apidoc configuration inside package.json file also:

```
...package.json file

  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "repo url..."
  },
  "apidoc": {
    "title": "My documentation title",
    // you can use all other config options here: http://apidocjs.com/#configuration
  },
  "author": "some guy",
  "license": ""
}

...rest of package.json file
```

Comment: I want to generate apidoc without writing any specific comments in my code.can it be possible?

Comment: Sadly no... With new sails 1.0 and it's machine as controller logic it could be done... But you would need to write your own module for it :)

Answer (score 2):

Swagger UI can be used to create professional api documentation. For sails js and swagger integration see this link :-

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-swagger

Comment: I want to generate apidoc automatically with api's request and response and i think swagger don't provide it.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Swagger does provide a way for you to test request and response in the generated docs.

Comment: I want tool that will analyze my code and generate api documentation with all apis and its possible request, responses. I just need to configure that tool in my project and all the stuff will be done by it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to generate the API doc with the structure of the response that you defined in your personalised actions?
From my experience, the only way that I was able to do this is by using hand written comments in each controller. I was able to force an API doc with hypermedia responses, instead of just the basic Model for each controller. 
If there's another way of doing this, please do share.

Comment: During my research I didn't come about any tool that does this automatically for Node.js. I have tried both API Docs and Sails-Swagger. The closest I got to having a doc that really specifies the correct response for an API is using comments (it's actually annotations, like in Symfony, the only difference being that Symfony uses annotations to generate entities... meanwhile, in Sails, they're just simple comments). Swagger does generate the doc from code, but it returns the structure of the model as response.